# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.This is a no-op

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a below code :

```
export class ProductsCategory extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    // Title page
    document.title = "products category";
    // Varables url
    let { getAllRows, changeOrder, changeTitle, changeIsActive } = new APIs().ProductsCategoryApi();
    this.state = {
        bindData: [],
        loading: true,
        getAllRowsUrl: getAllRows,
        changeTitleUrl: changeTitle,
        changeOrderUrl: changeOrder,
        changeIsActiveUrl: changeIsActive,
    };
    // Bind table
    this.bindTable();
}

bindTable = () => {
    // Bind table
    (async () => {
        let response = await fetch(this.state.getAllRowsUrl);
        // if HTTP-status is 200-299
        if (response.ok) {
            this.setState({
                bindData: await response.json(),
                loading: false
            });
            return;
        }
        Notify.bindData(false);
    })();
}

reloadTable = () => { }

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.bindTable();
}

render() {  Some code  };}
```

When change page, I see this error in console tab :

"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method"

Answer (score 0):

You need to cleanup the subscriptions. You can use `AbortController` to achieve that. Have a look at [this post](https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/how-to-clean-up-subscriptions-in-react-components-using-abortcontroller-72335f19b6f7)